# limit the number of times a method can be called in Java

Tags: java

How can I limit the amount of times addAddition() can be called? If, for example, I wanted to limit it to 4 times so after I call it 4 times in the Main class an error message would appear.

```
public class BaseBurger {
public void addAddition(int additionNumber) {
    switch (additionNumber) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Bacon added!");
            this.price += 3;
            i++;
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Salad added!");
            this.price += 2.5;
            i++;
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Juice added!");
            this.price += 3;
            i++;
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Sauce added!");
            this.price += 3.5;
            i++;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid value!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `if(i==4) throw new Error("Called  four times");`.  Note: if you start main method again the `i ` value will be reset

Comment: Don't use `Error` for that; an `IllegalStateException` would be appropriate.

Comment: You should manage this policy outside of the method, where those concerns originate.

Comment: Do you want to prevent adding an ingredient twice?

Comment: I want to avoid adding 4 ingredients in the same burger.

Comment: So if don't want Salad, Juice or Sauce, adding Bacon four times (but not five or more times) is OK?

Comment: Yes, it is ok. There's no problem adding an ingredient twice or more since it don't exceed the value of 4.

Comment: While what you asking about is certainly possible to do (as hinted by others before me), you're solving the problem in the wrong way. As an idea: if only 3 ingredients are allowed for a burger, a more robust solution would be to have an ingredient collection in the Burger class and `addIngredient(Ingredient ingredient)` method that throws an exception once the collection reaches the limit.

Answer (score -1):

Add a field to count the number of times your method is called. Once the maximum limit is reached, throw your error. Hence your code can be ...

```
public class BaseBurger {
  private int counter = 0;
  public void addAddition(int additionNumber) {
    if (counter == 4) throw new CUSTOM_ERROR();
    counter++; // increase counter each time. 
    switch (additionNumber) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Bacon added!");
            this.price += 3;
            i++;
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Salad added!");
            this.price += 2.5;
            i++;
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Juice added!");
            this.price += 3;
            i++;
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Sauce added!");
            this.price += 3.5;
            i++;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid value!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I doubt the counter should be `static`, since the limit is likely to prevent more than 4 ingredients to be added to a single burger.

Comment: The question is about having no more instances than 4, so a static value will hold the number of times the method is called independent of instances. The question isn't that clear to describe about ingredients.

Comment: No, it is not about limiting the number of *instances*, but about limiting the number of *calls* to the method. The question explicitly says that. It's about limiting the number of calls *per instance*, though it doesn't say so explicitly. --- Look at the name of the class, and what the `print` statements say. Base**Burger**. Add "Bacon", "Salad", "Juice", "Sauce". It makes sense for a program to limit a single burger to 4 additions (ingredients). It doesn't make sense to limit the totality of ingredients across all Burger instances to 4.

Comment: That has also been explicitly clarified in a [comment by OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61356061/limit-the-number-of-times-a-method-can-be-called-in-java/61356104?noredirect=1#comment108542373_61356061).

Comment: What about now? Such that each instance have it's own field to count the number of times it is called.

Comment: Better, but there is really no difference between your new `counter` and the already existing `i`. Testing `i` was [already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61356061/limit-the-number-of-times-a-method-can-be-called-in-java/61356104?noredirect=1#comment108542048_61356061) 23 hours ago.